# How to easily create a landscape xml based on portrait one?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I did a rewrite to a portrait xml (android screen).

How can I easily convert this to similar landscape xml?

change every horizontal to vertical.

what else?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_widget_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_main"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_status_image"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_weight=".22">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:src="@drawable/widget_icon_no_data"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
            <!--
                              Layout is necessary because the setVisibility of ProgressBar is not working 
                              through remote views in 2.1. So wrapped by this layout 
            -->

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/widget_progress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp" 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="39dp"
                    android:layout_height="39dp"
                    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout> <!-- Status image layout -->


        <!--
                            ========================================================================
                            * Information layout - contains all the texts 
                            ========================================================================
        -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_information"
            android:layout_width="188dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight=".58"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_destination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="\@ Home in"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="9dp"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout> <!-- Information layout -->
        <!--
                            ========================================================================
                            * Action layout - action buttons container
                            ========================================================================
        -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_action"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_drive_disabled" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="Drive!"
                android:textColor="@color/disabled_white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout> <!-- Action layout -->


</LinearLayout>
```

here is my screenshot:

[image]

How can I:

1. resize the question mark to be us smaller resolution?
2. reposition the text to fit in the middle area?
3. make the refresh icon and text center?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted your layout example in Android Studio, and after remove @drawable tags, I saw it perfectly proportioned in landscape layout, just pushing the portrait to landscape mode button.

So If may I suggest you, a posible solution is that you play with the resolution from the images in its different sizes (/res/drawable-* folders). I mean, just change your drawable tags from the landscape.xml to map into images that accurately render the horizontal layout.

Hope this help

Comment: in landscape: does vertical\horizontal - hight\width, stay the same orientation as in portrait? meaning at least the linear layout should change to vertical no? (wired that didn't ruin your landscape, no?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way in the latest Android versions is by going to Design mode of an XML (not Text)

Then from the menu, select option - Create Landscape Variation.
This will create a landscape xml without any hassle in a few seconds.

[image]

I hope this works for you.